# How does one set attributes for SD files?

Tags: sd

How does one set file attributes, e.g., creation date, for a file being created on an SD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Arduino SD library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD), is based on [Github: greiman/SdFat](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat), by William Greiman.

From [SD Created File Attributes](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=473869.0):

> The basic SD.h library doesn't set the attributes. You notice everything has the same creation date? The library doesn't have any way of knowing what the date is.

However, you need to use a callback function. The following information is from [file creation date and time in sd card ?](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348562.0):

> Install the SdFat library - there is an example called [Timestamp.ino](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/examples/Timestamp/Timestamp.ino) describing in detail how to do it...
>
> ```
> // after your rtc is set up and working you code just needs:
>
> void dateTime(uint16_t* date, uint16_t* time) {
>   DateTime now = rtc.now();
>
>   // return date using FAT_DATE macro to format fields
>   *date = FAT_DATE(now.year(), now.month(), now.day());
>
>   // return time using FAT_TIME macro to format fields
>   *time = FAT_TIME(now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second());
> }
>
> //put that outside of any functions, before your 'setup'
>
> //Then inside your 'loop' or 'setup'
>
> void loop(void)
> {
>
>   //Other code that does stuff
>
>   //put this next line *Right Before* any file open line:
>   SdFile::dateTimeCallback(dateTime);
>   dataFile = SD.open(datafilename, FILE_WRITE);
>
>   //other code that does stuff
>
> }
> ```

There is another way of achieving this, in a sketch without having to convert to SDFat:

> @donald0000 wants the Date Modified field to show an actual time stamp
>   when you look at the files present on the card using Windows Explorer.
>   As Billy Ho says, the callback function is the way to do it. You can
>   indeed use this function with `SD.h`  if you don't want to convert to
>   SDFat. Here is an example of the function in a sketch. Notice the
>   timing of when the date modified time stamp is written, it is when
>   `file.close()` writes the actual data to the card.
>
> ```
> #include <SPI.h>
> #include <SD.h>
> #include <Wire.h>
> #include <RTClib.h>
>
> File file;  // test file
> const uint8_t SD_CS = 10; // SD chip select
> RTC_DS1307 RTC;  // define the Real Time Clock object
>
>  char timestamp[30];
>
> //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> // call back for file timestamps
> void dateTime(uint16_t* date, uint16_t* time) {
>  DateTime now = RTC.now();
>  sprintf(timestamp, "%02d:%02d:%02d %2d/%2d/%2d \n", now.hour(),now.minute(),now.second(),now.month(),now.day(),now.year()-2000);
>  Serial.println("yy");
>  Serial.println(timestamp);
>  // return date using FAT_DATE macro to format fields
>  *date = FAT_DATE(now.year(), now.month(), now.day());
>
>  // return time using FAT_TIME macro to format fields
>  *time = FAT_TIME(now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second());
> }
> //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> void setup() {
>
>  Serial.begin(9600);
>  Wire.begin();
>  if (!RTC.begin()) {
>    Serial.println("RTC failed");
>    while(1);
>  };
>  // set date time callback function
>  SdFile::dateTimeCallback(dateTime);
>
>   DateTime now = RTC.now();
>   sprintf(timestamp, "%02d:%02d:%02d %2d/%2d/%2d \n", now.hour(),now.minute(),now.second(),now.month(),now.day(),now.year()-2000);
>   Serial.println("xx");
>   Serial.println(timestamp);
>
>
>  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
>    Serial.println("SD.begin failed");
>    while(1);
>  }
>  file = SD.open("TEST_SD.TXT", FILE_WRITE);
>  file.println("Testing 1,2,3...");
>
>  delay(5000);
>  file.close();
>  Serial.println("Done");
> }
> //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> void loop() {}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply `FAT16` only supports 1 date, normally Modified Date. `FAT32` has (limited) support for 3 dates (but AFAIK there is no Arduino library which supports `FAT32`).

Even then not all OS even support Creation Date. Windows has 2 different interpretations depending on application, Linux natively only supports Change Date, although extensions provide support for more dates.

Comment: the latest SDFAT library supports FAT32.